# branching based on two boolean variables

Tags: c++, if-statement, function-pointers, switch-statement, control-flow

Suppose I have two boolean variables, and I want to do completely different things based on their values. What is the cleanest way to achieve this?

**Variant 1:**

```
if (a && b)
{
    // ...
}
else if (a && !b)
{
    // ...
}
else if (!a && b)
{
    // ...
}
else
{
    // ...
}
```

**Variant 2:**

```
if (a)
{
    if (b)
    {
        // ...
    }
    else
    {
        // ...
    }
}
else
{
    if (b)
    {
        // ...
    }
    else
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

**Variant 3:**

```
switch (a << 1 | b)
{
case 0:
    // ...
    break;

case 1:
    // ...
    break;

case 2:
    // ...
    break;

case 3:
    // ...
    break;
}
```

**Variant 4:**

```
lut[a][b]();

void (*lut[2][2])() = {false_false, false_true, true_false, true_true};

void false_false()
{
    // ...
}

void false_true()
{
    // ...
}

void true_false()
{
    // ...
}

void true_true()
{
    // ...
}
```

Are variants 3 and 4 too tricky/complicated for the average programmer? Any other variants I have missed?

Comment: Why would you ever want to do 3 or 4? Looks horrible to me :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The first variant is the clearest and most readable, but it can be adjusted:

```
if (a && b) {
    // ...
} else if (a) { // no need to test !b here - b==true would be the first case
    // ...
} else if (b) { //no need to test !a here - that would be the first case
    // ...
} else { // !a&&!b - the last remaining
    // ...
}
```

Comment: As soon as the whole statement doesn't fit in one screen, it gets very unreadable. I don't find this clear at all.

Comment: @Alex: It's okay, I ended up not needing the fourth case at all, and now the whole thing fits on 13 lines (6 of which are just braces).

Comment: @Alexandre C: so don't write functions that don't fit on one screen ;-p

Comment: @Alexandre: why will this not fit on one screen? Just add function calls where the dots are and it's very compact and readable.

Comment: If `a` is false, are compilers smart enough to skip the second check and jump straight to the third check?

Comment: @FredOverflow: Can't tell without checking emitted assembly, but checking a `bool` is trivial anyway.

Answer (score 4):

You forgot about:

```
if (a) a_true(b);
else a_false(b);
```

which is probably the best choice when appliable, and when you truly need 4 different behaviours.

If you have more than 2 bools, I take this as a code smell if I have 2^n different behaviours which don't factorize well like the above. Then I may think about doing:

```
enum { case1, case2, ... }

int dispatch_cases(bool a, bool b, bool c, ..., bool z);

switch (dispatch_cases(a, b, ..., z))
{
case case1:
    ...
};
```

but without context, it is hard to tell whether such complexity is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, I will go for `variant 3`. Because personally, I don't like `if/else` when I am checking for equality. It clearly states that there are only 4 possibilities.

One minor edit would be:

```
inline int STATES(int X, int Y) { return (X<<1) | Y; }
// ...
switch (STATES(a,b))
```

To make it more fancy, you may replace `0,1,2,3` with an `enum` as well.

```
enum States {
  NONE,
  ONLY_B.
  ONLY_A,
  BOTH
};
```

Comment: Yet it fails to clearly state what that bit twiddling for. That's why I don't like it.

Comment: @Martinho, yes that's true. we can have some stuff there. I have tried to convey your message in edit version.

Comment: The definition of `true` is not zero.  It isn't necessarily one without some extra work, like `(X?2:0)|(Y?1:0)`

Answer (score 1):

For just two booleans, any of them is good and reasonable. One can choose based on his taste.

However, if there are more than two booleans, say *four* booleans, then I personally would go with lookup table, and I would do this as:

```
typedef void (*functype)();

//16 functions to handle 16 cases!
void f0() {}
void f1() {}
//...so on
void f15() {}

//setup lookup table
functype lut[] = 
{
    f0,   //0000 - means all bool are false
    f1,   //0001
    f2,   //0010
    f3,   //0011
    f4,   //0100
    f5,   //0101
    f6,   //0110
    f7,   //0111
    f8,   //1000
    f9,   //1001
    f10,  //1010
    f11,  //1011
    f12,  //1100
    f13,  //1101
    f14,  //1110
    f15   //1111 - means all bool are true
};

lut[MakeInt(b1,b2,b3,b4)](); //call
```

`MakeInt()` is easy to write:

```
int MakeInt(bool b1, bool b2, bool b3, bool b4)
{
   return b1 | (b2<<1) | (b3 <<2) | (b4<<3);
}
```

Comment: If there are more than two booleans, I try to figure out how to get rid of them.

Comment: @Alexandre: Even I would try to get rid of them. But if I fail? Then I would choose this approach.